# Explain "accumulated round-off error" for double values

Tags: java, int, double

I'm a self-taught beginner in java and having trouble understanding ints and doubles when used in the same equation

For example,

```
int x;
double x;
i = 5;

x = i / 2 + 1.0; // (answer 3.0)

z = (int) 1.0 + i / 2.0; // (answer 3.5)
```

What is with the rounding?

Comment: In addition to the answers, `z = (int) 1.0 + i / 2.0` does not do what you think. It is equivalent to `z = ((int) 1.0) + i / 2.0` where `1.0` is converted to `1` and then promoted to `1.0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this operation:

```
i / 2
```

... is performing an integer division. That's why `5 / 2` gives as result `2`, not `2.5`. This is normal behavior in Java, to perform a floating-point division you must make sure that at least one of the operands is a floating-point literal:

```
5 / 2.0
```

Now the above will return `2.5`, as expected. Alternatively, you can cast either one of the operands:

```
((double) i) / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A division involving two ints will yield an int (thus, 5 / 2 = 2). If you use a double in one of the operands, it will yield a double (thus 5 / 2.0 = 2.5). The rest is operation precedence.

Answer (score 0):

`i / 2 = int 2` because both operands are integers and so integer division operation is used (yielding integer result)

`i / 2.0 = double 2.5` because i is first coerced to double (type of the other operand) and double division is used

Answer (score 0):

This is a case between integer and decimal division.

When two integers are divided, integer division is performed, that is, where the numbers are divided and the decimal component truncated.

When any number of the two numbers in question is a decimal (double/float) every other number gets treated as a decimal such that given the expression 5 / 2.0. The result will be 2.5 returned in whatever type of object 2.0 was (double by default).

Given a mixed equation such as 5 / 2 + 1.0, operator precedence defines how the expression should be evaluated. Since division has a higher precedence than addition, 5 / 2 gets evaluated as a integer division, returning 2 as an integer.

This is then added to 1.0 where the 2 gets promoted to a double before evaluation, returning the number 3.0 as a double as the final result.